How to set serializer field without showing it to end user in DRF?
I have url like "doc/<int:doc_id>/price/" for get and post and "doc/<int:doc_id>/price/<int:id>" for delete and patch or retrieve.
My problem is, when creating a new price I want to set price.doc_id=self.kwargs\['doc_id'\], but at the same time I want that serializer field to be hidden in swagger documentation (I use drf-spectacular). The end user should not be aware of that field.
I know I can overwrite the create method of serializer and explicitly set the price or use serializers.save(doc=doc), but I ask this question to get a better solution. I tried hiddenfield as well, but apparently it only takes a default value and I do not know how to pass doc_id to it.
class DocPriceOutHistorySerializer(ModelSerializerWithValidator):

    currency_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    type_price_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.DictPriceList
        fields = (
            'id',
            'dat',
            'price',
            'currency',
            'currency_name',
            'type_price',
            'type_price_name',
            'obj',
            'doc',
        )

and in views.py
data = request.data
data['doc'] = self.kwargs['doc_id']
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
self.perform_create(serializer)

This will work, but I do not want to manually write a request schema for swagger.
